# simple probability question, two aces drawn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a pile of 6 cards that contains two aces. The cards are then sorted out into two separate piles. What is the chance that there is an ace in each pile?

My approach is that there are ${3 \choose 1} {3 \choose 1}$ or  $9$ ways such that the aces are in different piles. The total number of ways to  arrange  $6$ cards is $6! = 720$ ways. But since it doesn't matter which ace or card is in the given pile, we can treat them as indistinguishable. so there are $6!/2!\cdot 4! = 15$ distinct possible ways.

I am not sure if this approach makes sense as the probability of $9/15$ seems quite high.
Any help/feedback appreciated.

Comment: are the two piles equal? meaning 3 cards each pile?

Comment: @Halex Please read about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is absolutely correct. There are many ways to figure this. Suppose you and your friend Harry (the two aces) are in a group of six people which is going to be divided randomly into two teams of three; what are the chances that you and Harry end up on different teams? Well, there are five other people besides you; two of them are going to be on your team, three of them are going to be on the other team. So Harry (or anyone else you care to name) has three chances out of five of being on the other team. $3/5=9/15$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct.  The number 9/15 is high because, for the case where both aces are in the same pile, there aren't many way to arrange 2 aces amongst three cards, only 3 (just the positions of the non-ace card).  That is, 3 arrangements for both aces in one pile, 3 for both aces in the other pile, or a total of 6.  As you mention, there are 9 for the aces in separate piles, giving 9/(6+9).